# How to keep alive managed code objects passed to unmanaged code as SWIG shared_ptr's?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, swig, shared-ptr

So I want to allow my C++ code to decide when to destroy managed objects. (As they are passed to it as delegates to be called on C++ side events).

I have a simple objects structure: EventGenerator + Delegates.

In my managed side I hae a wrapper for EventGenerator and a wrapper for Delegates interface, from which (using `%feature("director")`) I create managed delegates. Inside my C++ code I use shared_pointers to keep delegates alive. I used SWIG feature `shared_ptr`.

I need my managed Delegates to be alive as long as EventGenerator is alive. Yet GC does not know about anu connection between EventGenerator and Delegates.

Yet I do not want to know when object gets destroyed on C# side of things - I want to allow C++ side to take controll (using shared_ptr's).

So what shall be done to SWIG shared pointer to be capable to sustain itself on he managed side of things?

The only solution I found was to extend EventGenerator object on C# side so that adding a delegate to it would add that delegate to a list. It works yet I hope for a beter solution.

Is there any way to make SWIG account such things using shared pointer ref counters? (so that delegates would get destroyed in managed code only after its C++ host died?)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to create a GCHandle to the managed objects using GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Normal);  The object will survive as long as that handle exists (until you call .Free()).  You could also pin the object but unless you're going to directly access the object pointer from C++ this is unnecessary and it prevents the object from being moved during heap compaction etc.

I highly recommend C++/CLI when doing .NET interop with C++.  If you're doing C++/CLI simply creating a private reference field:

`private:
    MyManagedClass^ fieldName;`

This will store a reference to the object, which will prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Is C++/CLI supported by mono/linux?

Comment: No, mixed mode assemblies naturally have unmanaged C/C++ code which is compiled for Win32/Win64 and includes calls to OS functions via the CRT functions so it wouldn't run on Linux despite Mono's support for managed code.